# Как добавить новые поля из комментариев Wordpress, только с определенной страницы категории?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть форма добавления комментариев для обределенного шаблона записи (**my_post.php**), отличная от основной формы для всего сайта. Есть код который не дает добавить комментарий, если  не заполнены дополнительные поля.
Есть код который я добавляю, для проверки заполненности поля, и если оно не заполнено говорю вернуться назад вот сам код:

```
    //ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНОСТЬ РЕЙТИНГА
add_filter( 'preprocess_comment', 'comm_rating_require_rating' );
function comm_rating_require_rating( $commentdata ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['rating'] ) || 0 === intval( $_POST['rating'] ) )
    wp_die('Ошибка: Вы не добавили оценку. Нажмите кнопку «Назад» в своем веб-браузере и повторно отправьте свой комментарий с оценкой.');
    return $commentdata;
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['rating_1'] ) || 0 === intval( $_POST['rating_1'] ) )
    wp_die('Ошибка: Вы не добавили оценку. Нажмите кнопку «Назад» в своем веб-браузере и повторно отправьте свой комментарий с оценкой.');
    return $commentdata;
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['rating_2'] ) || 0 === intval( $_POST['rating_2'] ) )
    wp_die('Ошибка: Вы не добавили оценку. Нажмите кнопку «Назад» в своем веб-браузере и повторно отправьте свой комментарий с оценкой.');
    return $commentdata;
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['rating_3'] ) || 0 === intval( $_POST['rating_3'] ) )
    wp_die('Ошибка: Вы не добавили оценку. Нажмите кнопку «Назад» в своем веб-браузере и повторно отправьте свой комментарий с оценкой.');
    return $commentdata;
}
```

Но мне нужна проверка только тогда когда комментарии добавляется из записи с выбраным шаблоном **my_post.php**, я думал сделать для этого условие

```
if ( is_page_template('my_post.php')) {// тут необходимый код на проверку}
```

Данный код я вставляю в файл function.php, но если добавляю условие то он не работает совсем, а если убираю то он работает глобально для всех форм комментирования.

Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так?

Comment: Надо в файл вставлять, а внутрь функции comm_rating_require_rating()

Comment: Что куда вставлять?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
function comm_rating_require_rating( $commentdata ) {

 $template = get_page_template_slug( $commentdata['comment_post_ID'] );
 if('my_post.php' === $template) {
        // код
 }

}
```

хотя is_page_template должен работать

Comment: Не работает, я уже все перепробовал.

Comment: получать id из `$commentdata['comment_post_ID']` пробовали?